# Sending email with javascript on custom button

Tags: javascript, email-template, custom-button

I am trying to select the appropriate email template using javascript on a custom button.  Here is a stripped down version of my code:

```
var template; 
var type = "{!My_Custom_Object__c.My_Field__c}"; 
if(type == "Quick") { 
template = "00XV0000000DlRB"; 
}
location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?p3_lkid={!My_Custom_Object__c.Id}&p24=james.hyland1@verizon.net&p5=&template_id=template')
```

If I replace the end of the last line with `template_id=00XV0000000DlRB`, it works; but if I use the variable template, it says `template_id contains a character that is not allowed`.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

template is a varible, so you should concatenate it to literal string by using "**+**".

```
 '...emplate_id='+template
```

Try this:

```
var template='';
if("{!My_Custom_Object__c.My_Field__c}" == "Quick") { 
   template = "&template_id=00XV0000000DlRB"; 
}
location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?p3_lkid={!My_Custom_Object__c.Id}&p24=james.hyland1@verizon.net'+template)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm confused by the "'" before the plus.  Is that syntax correct?

Comment: the quotes were justo to highlight the symbol. you only have to concatenate doing: `"your-url"+valiable`